# Will certbot actually renew my certificate?

Tags: ssl-certificate, cron, ubuntu-18.04, lets-encrypt, certbot

Looking at `/etc/cron.d/certbot`, I don't think it will!  That file includes the line:

`0 */12 * * * root test -x /usr/bin/certbot -a \! -d /run/systemd/system && perl -e 'sleep int(rand(43200))' && certbot -q renew`

and, unless I'm reading it wrong, renewal will only happen if there's a readable, executable file called `/usr/bin/certbot` (there is) AND if there's *not* a directory called `/run/systemd/system` (but there is, even though it's empty).

So am I right and the `certbot -q renew` bit will never run?  Is there perhaps somewhere else that also triggers the renewal?  (I thought there might be something in `/run/systemd/system` because that's being checked, but as I said, there's not.  Out of curiosity, why *does* this little script check for the non-existence of `/run/systemd/system`?)

This is running the latest `certbot` (v1.18.0, installed yesterday using [the official instructions](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntubionic-apache)) on Ubuntu 18.04.

By the way, I have run:

`test -x /usr/bin/certbot -a \! -d /run/systemd/system && perl -e 'sleep int(rand(43200))' && certbot renew --dry-run`

as root on the command line, and it exits immediately with an exit status of 1.

Comment: The cron job is obsolete (and its continued presence in the package is an error); use the systemd timer instead.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I just assumed it was maybe for a different and/or old(er) Linux distro.  Its presence did confuse me!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the system is using `systemd`, it will run as a systemd service, triggered by time.

If you run `systemctl status certbot.timer` you will get the status of the service that triggers `certbot` from systemd.

This is why the cron script is configured not to run renewal if systemd is detected on the machine.

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense.  Should I be concerned that when I run that `systemctl` command, the output includes `Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2021-09-06 15:36:46 BST; 18h ago`?

Comment: In answer to my own extra question above, [it seems I shouldn't be concerned](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/certbot-inactive/148403/2) about it.